# Laravel Socialite redirection issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have followed this tutorial to login using facebook:

[social-auth](http://tutsnare.com/social-authentication-in-laravel-5/)

I am able to login using facebook but after that it just redirects to [http://localhost:8000/auth/login#*=*](http://localhost:8000/auth/login#_=_).

Comment: are you handling the callback? I assume you are login with favebook...

Comment: Need to see the code in your controller (both methods), config for facebook and routes. 
I think the most possible is that after you are handling the callback, you redirect back to 'auth/login', which might cause the issue